# Field value as Views 3 block title

Tags: views, blocks

I have a Views 3 block whose block title I would like to set using PHP in the header section. This would enable me to use tokens from the views results, which is *not* possible from the UI.

In the case of a views *page* I was able to set the page title via the following PHP command in the header section:

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->build_info['title'] = 'My Page Title';
```

However, I was *not* able to do the same thing for block titles via

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->build_info['title'] = 'My Block Title';
```

This is probably because the `build_info['title']` command only edits the page (or node) title. Does anyone know of an analogous command to set *block* titles?

Comment: Both the page and the block are subviews of a view (or a collection of views). The page view is the master view. Maybe views_get_current_view() only loads the _master_ view? Is there a command to load a _subview_? Something like views_get_current_view()->subview?

Comment: i guess you can change title of view in `YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I made a huge mistake. When I tried to achieve the same thing for the block title, I copied the code from the page header but didn't *remove* it from the page header. In other words, I used the PHP commands - *exactly* as described in the question - in the headers of two subviews of the *same* view *simultaneously*. To be more precise, the variable `$view` was used in two places, which caused an error.

When I replace

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
$view->build_info['title'] = 'My Block Title';
```

with

```
$view_block = views_get_current_view();
$view_block->build_info['title'] = 'My Block Title';
```

things work as desired!

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Views (3.14), you can write tokens in the view title.

It doesn't say so in any help messages, but I have tested it on https://simplytest.me and it worked.

You can see the available token names by selecting the last field and activating `Rewrite the output of this field` and folding out `Replacement patterns`.

Comment: This just saved me so much headache. I wish I could upvote this like 20 times.